# Error: adding rows with smartsheet API

Tags: smartsheet-api

I can't seem to get a add row(s) to work.  I get the following error, but I believe the data is formatted correctly. Thanks in advance!

{"errorCode":1008,"message":"Unable to parse request. The following error occurred: Request body must be either a JSON object or JSON array."}

POST https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/sheet/{sheetId}/rows

ContentType=application/json

```
[
  {
   "toBottom" : true, 
   "cells" : [
        {"columnId" : "328984295696260", "value" : 888.0},
        {"columnId" : 4832583923066756, "value" : 100.0}
    ]
  },
  {
   "toBottom" : true, 
   "cells": [
      {"columnId" : "328984295696260", "value" : 999.0},
      {"columnId" : 4832583923066756, "value" : 100.0}
    ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've encountered a bug with the **API 1.1** "Add Row(s)" endpoint. I get the same error as you report when attempting a similar request using the API 1.1 endpoint -- but it works fine with the API 2.0 endpoint.

I'd suggest that you try using the **API 2.0** "Add Row(s)" endpoint instead:

`POST https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetId}/rows`

API 1.1 has been deprecated (see announcement [here](https://www.smartsheet.com/blog/july-2015-api-v2-launch)), so you should be using API 2.0 for any new API development. The API 2.0 documentation can be found [here](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/).

PS - for good measure (although it's not the cause of your issue) -- I'd suggest that you remove quotation marks from around the first numerical **columnId** value in each **cells** collection, as they're not necessary.